# How to tell which of the two FTP server running is serving an FTP request?

Tags: ftp, sftp, vsftpd

I was asked to reconfigure and make some order in a FTP server which is operating on Ubuntu 10.04. I have root access to the machine.

When checking what server is running, I get:

```
# ps -ef | grep ftp
root      2287     1  0 Mar19 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/vsftpd
root     26380 26369  0 Jun27 ?        00:00:02 /usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server
```

From the man pages I understand that `vsftpd` and `sftp-server` are both FTP server software. How can I tell which server is actually serving an FTP request from a remote machine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sftp-server` does not serve FTP requests. It is for SFTP, which is actually SSH and not FTP at all.

Comment: OK, so does this mean that the only FTP server I have running is the `vsftpd`? If so why sftp is called sFTP? To quote from the `sftp` man page: "     sftp is an interactive file transfer program, similar to ftp(1), which performs all operations over an encrypted ssh(1) transport."

Comment: Yes. The man page says that because it is *similar* to ftp. It allows for providing an ftp-like interface on top of ssh. But you cannot connect to it with a regular ftp connection.